# Creating a relative path to known folder

Tags: c#, file, path, directory

I'm looking for a way to make a list of files from a relative filepath.

So far I've come up with this:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"~\Images\Uploaded\");
```

But I get an error which says that the path doesn't exist, although it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is an ASP.Net application you can use Server.MapPath to convert relative path to absolute path

```
string folderPath = Server.MapPath("~\Images\Uploaded\");
```

From the [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12373394/649524)

You can use [Directory.GetcurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the current directory, and [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) to combine with relative path to form absolute path and get the files from this absolute path.

Try following

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),@"\Images\Uploaded\"));
```

or just use the relative path without using `~`

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"\Images\Uploaded\"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried it myself, but I'm curious about `Directory.GetFiles(VirtualPathUtility.GetDirectory(@"~\Images\Uploaded\"));`

[VirtualPathUtility documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.virtualpathutility.aspx)